# How To Know All Asynchronous HTTP Calls are Completed

Tags: java, multithreading, http, asynchronous, okhttp

I am trying to figure out how to determine if all async HTTP GET requests I've made have completed, so that I can execute another method. For context, I have something similar to the code below:

```
public void init() throws IOException {
    Map<String, CustomObject> mapOfObjects = new HashMap<String, CustomObject>();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // some code to populate the map

    mapOfObjects.forEach((k,v) -> {
        HttpClient.asyncGet("https://fakeurl1.com/item/" + k, createCustomCallbackOne(k, mapper)); 
        // HttpClient is just a wrapper class for your standard OkHTTP3 calls, 
        // e.g. client.newcall(request).enqueue(callback);
        HttpClient.asyncGet("https://fakeurl2.com/item/" + k, createCustomCallbackTwo(k, mapper));
    });
}


private createCustomCallbackOne(String id, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try (ResponseBody body = response.body()) {
                    CustomObject co = mapOfObjects.get(id);
                    if (co != null) {
                        co.setFieldOne(mapper.readValue(body.byteStream(), FieldOne.class))); 
                    }                       
                } // implicitly closes the response body                
            }    
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            // log error                
        }
    }
}

// createCustomCallbackTwo does more or less the same thing, 
// just sets a different field and then performs another 
// async GET in order to set an additional field
```

So what would be the best/correct way to monitor all these asynchronous calls to ensure they have completed and I can go about performing another method on the Objects stored inside the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way would be to keep a count of how many requests are 'in flight'. Increment it for each request enqueued, decrement it at the end of the callback. When/if the count is 0, any/all requests are done. Using a semaphore or counting lock you can `wait` for it to become 0 without polling.

Note that the callbacks run on separate threads, so you must provide some kind of synchronization.

If you want to create a new callback for every request, you could use something like this:

```
public class WaitableCallback implements Callback {

  private boolean done;
  private IOException exception;

  private final Object[] signal = new Object[0];

  @Override
  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
      ...
      synchronized (this.signal) {
        done = true;
        signal.notifyAll();
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    synchronized (signal) {
      done = true;
      exception = e;
      signal.notifyAll();
    }
  }

  public void waitUntilDone() throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (this.signal) {
      while (!this.done) {
        this.signal.wait();
      }
    }
  }

  public boolean isDone() {
    synchronized (this.signal) {
      return this.done;
    }
  }

  public IOException getException() {
    synchronized (this.signal) {
      return exception;
    }
  }

}
```

Create an instance for every request and put it into e.g. a `List<WaitableCallback> pendingRequests`.

Then you can just wait for all requests to be done:

```
for ( WaitableCallback cb : pendingRequests ) {
  cb.waitUntilDone();
}
// At this point, all requests have been processed.
```

However, you probably should not create a new identical callback object for every request. Callback's methods get the `Call` passed as parameter so that the code can examine it to figure out which request it is processing; and in your case, it seems you don't even need that. So use a single Callback instance for the requests that should be handled identically.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. However, I'm not sure I fully understand how to implement this solution in my current code, i.e. I'm not sure if you're saying to replace my current callbacks with WaitableCallback or to wrap the existing ones in WaitableCallback. Could you update your code to showcase how I should use this in my code?

Comment: You can do either as you like. If you have multiple different Callback implementations you may want to use the delegator pattern to be able to use the 'waitable' functionality with any of them.

Answer (score 1):

If the function  asyncGet calls your function createCustomCallbackOne then its easy.

For each key you are calling two pages. "https://fakeurl1.com/item/" and "https://fakeurl2.com/item/" (left out + k)

So you need a map to trach that and just one call back function is enough.

Use a map with key indicating each call:

```
  static final  Map<String, Integer> trackerOfAsyncCalls = new HashMap<>();
  public void init() throws IOException {
    Map<String, CustomObject> mapOfObjects = new HashMap<String, CustomObject>();
//need to keep a track of the keys in some object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 trackerOfAsyncCalls.clear();
// some code to populate the map

mapOfObjects.forEach((k,v) -> {
    HttpClient.asyncGet("https://fakeurl1.com/item/" + k, createCustomCallback(k,1 , mapper)); 

    // HttpClient is just a wrapper class for your standard OkHTTP3 calls, 
    // e.g. client.newcall(request).enqueue(callback);
    HttpClient.asyncGet("https://fakeurl2.com/item/" + k, createCustomCallback(k, 2, mapper));
           trackerOfAsyncCalls.put(k + "-2", null);
        });
}
```

//final important 
  private createCustomCallbackOne(final String idOuter, int which, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    return new Callback() {
        final String myId = idOuter + "-" + which;

```
    trackerOfAsyncCalls.put(myId, null);
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
             trackerOfAsyncCalls.put(myId, 1);
            ///or put outside of if if u dont care if success or fail or partial...
```

Now set up a thread or best a schduler that is caclled every 5 seconds, check all eys in mapOfObjects and trackerOfAsyncCalls to see if all keys have been started and some final success or timeout or error status has been got for all.